# SegFault error in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, multidimensional-array

I have this code and when I compile it, it says Segmentation Fault after the first printf.
I don't know what is the cause of the problem. Please help. Thanks.

```
int main()
{
    char puzzle[7][7];
    char input[7];
    int i;
    int j;
    int a;

    printf("Enter your Tentaizu Puzzle:\n");

    while (input[a] = '\n') {
        scanf("%c", &input[a]);
        a++;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(input); a++) {
        j = 0;
        while (j < 7) {
            if (input[a] != ' ') {
                puzzle[i][j] = input[a];
                j++;
            }
        }
        a++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample input
. 2 . . . . .
1 . . . . 1 .
. . 1 2 . . 2
. . 4 3 . . .
. . . . . 3 .
1 . . . 1 . .
. . . . . . .

Comment: what is 'a' here? it is taking garbage value.

Comment: If I remove it, it gives error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So many problems...  I've updated your code with `!!` comments.  I'm not really clear what you are actually trying to accomplish. As per your description, the input is read one line at a time, and all non space characters are placed into the array.  The code now checks for lines with too many and too few items.

```
int main()
{
    char puzzle[7][7];
    char input[256]; // !! Room for 49 chars, spaces and NUL
    char *p;
    int x, y;

    printf("Enter your Tentaizu Puzzle:\n");

    for (y = 0; y < 7; y++) {
        // !! use fgets to read a line; it will NUL terminate the string, and not overflow the buffer !!
        if (fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) == NULL) {
            perror("fgets");
            exit(1);
        }

        // !! don't call strlen when scanning, just check for NUL terminator, and increment i instead of a !!
        for(x = 0, p = input; *p; p++) {
            // !! what was a had the same value as i, so we only need i !!
            // !! filter out the newline that fgets might leave !!
            if (!isspace(*p)) {
                if (x < 7) {
                    puzzle[x++][y] = *p;
                 }
                 else {
                    printf("line too long\n");
                    exit(1);
                 }
            }
        }

        if(x < 7) {
            printf("line too short\n");
            exit(1);
         }
    }

    for(y = 0; y < 7; y++) {
        for(x = 0; x < 7; x++) {
            printf("%c ", puzzle[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The user will input a 7X7 puzzle and every character are spaced. By the end of the last line, the program should stop. But when i tried your code, the loop does not end after the 7th row.

Comment: Yes, it's basically your code with the segfault fixed.  Your code wouldn't end after the 7th row either. Could you give an example input, and explain how you want it to end up in `puzzle`?

Comment: i put a sample input their. What I wanted to happen is when the user inputs the last line and when he enters, the program will end.

Comment: last question: how do I print the input and where will I put it?

Comment: do you mean, how do you print the input once it's loaded into the `puzzle` array?  What do you mean by, "where will I put it"?

Comment: yes. because when i wrote printf("%c\n", puzzle[x][y]); it doesn't print anything

Comment: Where did you add this `printf`?  I have updated the answer to show how to print the `puzzle` after reading it.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to set `a` to equal zero at the start of your program.
a is being initialized to some unspecified, mostly likely huge number.
When you index input at `a`, you are indexing way out of `input`s bounds (7).

Comment: you can check one of the responses as a answer (its a giant green check mark underneath the number / updown label). Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize variables. Otherwise they will not have zero as their initial value. So I think you have to initialize `a=0`.

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize a to zero to prevent garbage value (if the garbage value is < 0 or > 6 the segmentation fault is normal as your array has a size of 7).

Plus, you should rethink your while loop, as you want to stop when the user enters '\n', if you press enter, input[a] == '\n' but you increment a so the tested value won't be input[a] (which is '\n') but input[a+1] which is '\0' or a garbage value but certainly not the '\n' you want as a stop value.

You can switch

```
while(input[a] = '\n'){
    scanf("%c", &input[a]);
    a++;
}
```

with

```
while(a < 7){
    scanf("%c", &input[a]);
    if (input[a] == '\n')
        break;
    a++;
}
```